# No hot water in all washrooms

Tags: plumbing

The faucets in the laundry (basement) and kitchen (main floor above the laundry) has hot water, however, all other faucets including shower on the main floor and 2nd floor have no hot water.  When you turn ON the faucet to HOT, no water comes out.  And this all happened at the same time.  Is it possible that the faucets broke at the same time?

Comment: Sounds like a pipe has frozen.  Conduct your research and troubleshooting as such.

Comment: This could be caused by a variety of issues, it could have frozen or there could be a unnoticeable split somewhere, does the cold still work on that floor?